# requiring asset files from subdirectories of the asset path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm in the process of trying to upgrade my app to Rails 3.1, and I have quite a lot of custom Javascript files that I'm trying to migrate to the new assets pipeline.

My current (that is, pre-3.1) directory structure has something like:

```
public/
    foo/
        model.js
        controller.js
        etc...
```

So, I'm trying to move these to lib/assets/javascripts and keep the foo/ subdirectory intact (rather than make foo_model.js, foo_controller.js, etc).

In my application.js I tried to do:

```
//= require foo/model
```

and

```
//= require 'foo/model'
```

But these don't work. Rails always gives me an error page and says:

```
couldn't find file 'foo/model.js'
```

I did test that things get correctly included if they're not in the subdirectory, so I know it's not just that my lib/assets directory is not in the include path or something. So I guess I'm just wondering if there's a way to do this, or should I just be flattening the directories and using foo_model.js and such?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like rails only add one level of subdirectories to assets paths

You can check with current paths by running `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` at rails console

add absolute path of your folders at application.rb like

```
config.assets.paths += ["/path/to/lib/assets/javascript/foo"]
```

Comment: So according to the Sprockets usage webpage (http://getsprockets.org/installation_and_usage) you're supposed to be able to do like:

    //= require <foo/model>

But this doesn't seem to work.  I'm not sure if it's a bug or if I'm just doing something wrong. That seems more ideal to me, but your solution is the one that actually works so I'm giving you the credit . :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why rails only adds one level of subdirectories, but you can surely add additional (fully qualified) paths to the pipeline in config/application.rb. The docs lead to the answer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

For example:

`config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/flash"`